# Hangout bot is not available to Users after Publishing

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am pretty new to Hangout concept.
I have implemented various bot using Microsoft Bot framework.
This time I need to implement and publish a Google Hangout Bot using [this](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-publish?authuser=0) link.
As Azure yet not provide Google hangout channel for Bot.

As per this documentation when I publish the Bot, It should be available to domain users to discover this Bot.
But somehow I am not able to discover in Hangout.
Initially I want to just be able to publish a default Bot and make it available to all users in domain and in chat room.

I think I am missing something here.

Things I have tried is just created an Bot in Microsoft Bot framework and published using [this](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-publish?authuser=0) link.

Comment: Why would a bot made with Microsoft Bot Framework work magically by just referencing its api endpoint on Google Hangout side? There is no magic there, MS Bot Framework does not match exactly what Google is using to communicate between Hangout and a bot, so you can't do that just like that. As Amit said in a reply, you have to make a connector if you want that the both sides understand each other

Comment: @NicolasR , I am not  sure how I would make a connector and how to  use it in the flow..

Comment: Honestly it's not so easy and i would not suggest that you try. For me MS bot framework is not made to target Hangout (at least at the moment), so you should not use it for your need here

Comment: @NicolasR, Yes , you are right - MS bot framework is not made to target Hangout. I am trying to implement my own node.js server API to serve the purpose. And for this also I will need to create a connector. But not sure - How?. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't help you more on that sorry, I'm not working on Hangout

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a connector/bridge to the hangouts API.
Take a look at the interface on the docs  [Interface IConnector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iconnector.html)

You can choose whether to use the DirectlineAPI or create the connection on your own.

See an example of an implementation for line [on this repo](https://github.com/Wolke/botbuilder-linebot-connector)

Besides, you should make sure you have all the configurations ready on Google's side (the instructions are on the link you've posted)

Comment: Thanks Amit, Surely this will helpful while starting conversation between Bot and user. Right now I am stuck as I could not discover the published bot in my Hangout chat window. I followed all instructions on the link..

Comment: I would suggest sending an email to Google's support, it's a new platform so bugs might still exist